# External Content Types Filters

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, external-content-type

I have created an external content type to connect to a SQL database to show client information in SharePoint 2013, once the connection was created I created a list to display all the info

I then created two filters:

Filter 1 = Is a wildcard filter to allow users to search for client names in the picker

Filter 2 = This limit the number of results in the picker

[image]

Picker

[image]

Since I created the wildcard filter all of the items in the list have disappeared

[image]

How do I display all the clients in the list again?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should create two operations

1. Read List - This should not have any filters applied and this should be used by the List
2. Read Item - This should have the filters and will be used for filtering

Comment: Hello, I tried to edit the read item operation but it did not give me any options to apply filters

Comment: It's available in the input parameter screen, select the parameter and click the filter link on right.

Comment: Thanks, I have found that now but it does not allow me to create the wildcard filter, I added a screenshot above